# Select count of customers that purchased at least one from two specific categories in the same month

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to write a query to count the customers that purchased at least one from `order_type=0` and one `order_type=1` during the same month in 2014

I have two tables.

The **order** table that have:

- order_id
- customer_id
- aquisition_date

**orders_category** table:

- order_id
- order_type (the type of the orders it may have 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ...etc )

I tried with this query but it didn't work, I know it's not complete and I missed the month condition!

```
Select count(user_id) From order
join orders_category
 on order.order_id = orders_category.order_id
Where (order_type=0 or order_type=1)
and extract (year from order.aquisition_date)=2014
group by user_id
having count (case when type_id=0 then null else null end) > 0
and count (case when type_id=1 then null else null end) > 0;
```

I don't know how to find users with at least 1 order from `order_type=0` & 1 order of `order_type=1`, in the same month.

Comment: I don't see how you expect either of your case statements to do anything; both sides of the case are NULL, and therefore they can never be greater than 0, so there will never be a row having a count that matches. Read what you wrote: `count (case when type_id = 0 then NULL else NULL end)`. How does that return a value > 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query, based on what you already had. However, I suggest you change the name of the table `order` to `orders` as `order` is a reserved word:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from   (
    select     user_id, month(aquisition_date) 
    from       orders
    inner join order_category
            on orders.order_id = order_category.order_id
    where      order_type in (0, 1)
    and        year(aquisition_date) = 2014
    group by   user_id, month(aquisition_date)
    having     count(distinct order_type) = 2
) as base
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60a38/1)

I selected the month also in the sub-select, as it will be interesting to look at the output of that query on its own during your analysis.

Comment: you are an absolute genius! Thank you so much :D @trincot